# What is the dimension of Avogadro's constant?

Tags: atoms, units

What is the dimension of Avogadro's constant ($N_\mathrm{A}$).

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant) it says it is dimensionless, but [in Nigel Wheatley's article (pdf) *On the dimensionality of the Avogadro constant and the definition of the mole*](https://www.nature.com/articles/npre.2010.5138.1.pdf) it says it is $\mathsf{N}^{-1}$.

\begin{align}
\text{Number of particles} &= N_\mathrm{A}\times \text{Amount of substance}\\
[\text{Amount of substance}] &= \mathsf{N}\\
[\text{Number of particles}] &= \mathsf{1}
\end{align}

If $[N_\mathrm{A}] = \mathsf{N}^{-1}$ then the above equation follows, otherwise it doesn't. Is this the right value?

Comment: See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/108506/79678

Comment: Mildly related question about the *value* of $N_\mathrm{A}$ (not the units): [What is the correct value of the Avogadro constant? And how was it derived?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32443)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dimension/unit of the **Avogadro constant $N_\mathrm{A}$** is actually $1/\mathsf{N}$ or $\pu{mol-1}$. It is shown that way in your first reference as well, i.e.
$$ N_\mathrm{A} = \pu{6.02214076E23 mol-1}. $$

What is "dimensionless" is the **Avogadro number** or the number of atoms / molecules in a single $\pu{mol}$ of that substance, sometimes written as $N$ or $N_0$.

The numerical value is the same, but the *concept* is different. Basically the relationship between the two is:
$N_0 = (\pu{1 mol})\times N_\mathrm{A} = \pu{6.02214076E23}$

See also the answer discussed in the comment by Ed V, where the new definition of the constant is explained: [Effects of Changing Avogadro's Constant](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/108506).

Answer (score 1):

The dimensions of Avogadro's Constant is $1/\mathsf{N}$. In SI units, this is $\pu{1/mol}$.

Your unit analysis is correct. I have seen this type of question before, I believe the confusion is caused by people normally saying *particles per mole*, and "particles" is a "phantom" unit (similar to radian). But either way, the SI units are definitely $\pu{1/mol}$.